# How to specify one or more instances of a special character using regex

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to match a doc name:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]\.txt
```

Doc

```
asdf2342l_asdf2_asdf23.txt
```

The Underscore can appear at any point in time before the .txt, but so far i have been unsuccessful in

?

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]\.txt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the quantifier: `+` or `*` in this case.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a quantifier, for example:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.txt
```

plus sign means: "at least one character or more", so it will match all characters before ".txt" part.

But I recommend you don't try specify all possible characters in first part of file name (because it could contain Unicode symbols f.e.). Try use this regex:

```
[^.]+\.txt$
```

It will match every file name, that have .txt extension. If you have full path in  file names (disk, parent folder(s) + path separators), you should use this one:

```
[^.\\\/]+\.txt$
```

Comment: or use the alpha-numeric class

    [[:alnum:]_]+\.txt

And note that the + quantifier is only available when using extended regex. For basic regex' you'd have to use:

    [[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\.txt